# How to merge two different pages on one page

Tags: views, 7, users, routes

I am using profile 2 module to manage users profile related information.
so far I am having two tabs

1. My Accounts
2. Customize the tabs takes me to two different URLs 
   i.e
   (mydomain.com/users/user-name/edit/Customize)
   (mydomain.com/users/user-name/edit/MyAccounts)

My question is, 
can I make this into one tab and make these two different pages to display in one single page?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Hide the tab on the user account page.

```
function MY_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user_category/edit/profile']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

Then, merge the profile2 form with the user account form itself :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for the user edit form.
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (($type = profile2_get_types('profile')) && $type->userCategory) {
    if (empty($form_state['profiles'])) {
      $profile = profile2_load_by_user($form['#user'], 'profile');
      if (empty($profile)) {
        $profile = profile_create(array('type' => 'profile', 'uid' => $form['#user']->uid));
      }
      $form_state['profiles'][$profile->type] = $profile;
    }
    profile2_attach_form($form, $form_state);
  }
}
```

From http://www.jide.fr/english/add-profile2-form-directly-on-the-user-edit-form

Comment: @user1414193 great. Then choose the correct answer by clicking the tick icon below the vote up/down buttons.